# Huawei SCP (SuperCharge Protocol) decoy trigger?

Tags: usb, usb-pd

So there are a ton of USB-PD decoy triggers, but they only allow for 5v@3a. However, I'd really love to be able to trigger the SCP 5v@4.5a mode on the 65W battery packs I'm using. I'm not charging phones, just pulling 5v for wearable LED strips. Generally not using more than 1.5-2a, but that's with patterns and not all the LEDs on at once, that sort of thing. So I'd like some extra headroom that 5v@4.5a can give me, just in case. I haven't found at USB-PD 3.1 EPR 5v5a battery packs that are of reasonable size (roughly 6"x2.5"x1").

And then I realized what `SCP` stood for on my current battery packs spec, which says 5v@4.5A SCP. Stands for SuperCharge Protocol, from Huawei. So now I'm on the hunt to see if there's a decoy trigger I can exploit for that. Or is there a simple resistor on data line thing that I can use, with appropriately sized +/- wiring on a custom USB-A end? I haven't been able to find any information at all about the protocol itself, other than it's specs.

Haven't found any on Amazon, found [this single one](https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256805214430392.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.13.25efmvSpmvSpZn&algo_pvid=4dee9025-2716-4a6a-8037-5b238c17932f&algo_exp_id=4dee9025-2716-4a6a-8037-5b238c17932f-6&pdp_npi=3%40dis%21USD%215.32%212.02%21%21%215.32%21%21%402101d91e16906901815917585e4809%2112000032910199998%21sea%21US%210&curPageLogUid=1y6r3rh4RLv5) on AliExpress, but it's actually physically on the larger size and will take longer than I have before my next trip to get.